# Sum the number of hours in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time, office-for-mac

I want to sum the total hours I was worked in a project. For each day, I have:

```
Starting Time B1: 09:30:00 am
Ending Time   C1: 17:00:00 pm
Total Hours   D1: =C1-B1 (06:30)
```

I want to sum the values from column `D` resulting in the total of hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! Use the formula `=SUM(D:D)` and **Format Cell** with the following *Custom*: `[h]:mm`.

The behaviour of `[h]` is defined [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/create-a-custom-number-format-HP010342372.aspx).

> `[h]`: Displays elapsed time in hours. If you are working with a formula that
>   returns a time in which the number of hours exceeds 24, use a number
>   format that resembles [h]:mm:ss.

Comment: You're correct. But you're formula is not. I think you meant `=C1-B1` (or your cell-naming is not correct). Either way... if you are a night-dweller and work after midnight you might want to change the formula to `=C1-B1+IF(C1<B1,1)`. In that case if the end-time is after midnight (and smaller than begin-time) there is a day added and your calculation is still correct.